# Sending emails with Alibaba Direct Mail SDK

Tags: javascript, sdk, alibaba-cloud, alibaba-cloud-direct-mail

First question ever, sorry for any mistake.

Since using Mautic+Alibaba Direct Mail has a big bottleneck which is the amount of emails per second it can send through SMTP, I'm trying to send emails using Alibaba Direct Mail SDK. I even found a great post here (https://github.com/FEMessage/direct-mail#table-of-contents) that should solve my problem, but since i'm a newbie on dev things aren't quite coming out.

Does someone know how can i create this script to send emails on Alibaba Direct Mail through the SDK?

Comment: Hi Felipe. Welcome to SO! The doc on `FEMessage/direct-mail` pretty much explains how to send emails. However, it's in Nodejs. Is your issue with sending emails or with bottleneck? Perhaps you could explain more on the issue you're facing and what you've tried so far.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.